# Average Magnitude of Magnetic Field inside a Toroidal Coil

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, integration

I want to find the average magnitude of magnetic field inside a toriodal coil (I will be using toroidal coil and toroid interchangeably) of a circular cross-section, like this:

[image: Toroid]

**Notations:**

$N=$ Number of turns of toroidal coil

$I=$ Current carried by the coil

$r_1=$ Inner radius of the toroid

$r_2=$ Outer radius of the toroid

$R=$ Radius of the cross-section of the toroid $=\frac{r_2-r_1}{2}$

[image: Notations]

The toroid is positioned horizontally, so when viewed from above, it looks like a ring or annulus. The plane containing the ring will be called the horizontal plane and the one perpendicular to it will the vertical plane which passes through the center of the toroid.

**Assumptions:**

1. The wound wire has negligible diameter.
2. N is sufficiently large that the magnetic field at a fixed distance from the centre of toroid is constant.

Now I know that with Ampère's circuital law (ACL), we can find that the magnetic field inside the toroid with $$B = \frac{\mu_0 NI}{2\pi r}$$ where

$r=$ radius of the circular Ampèrian loop.

Now, when we ask what is the average magnetic field inside the toroid is usually given as $$B_\text{average} = \frac{\mu_0 NI}{2\pi r_\text{average}}$$

where $r_\text{average}=\frac{r_1+r_2}{2}$

I couldn't find the derivation of the radius where the magnetic field matches the average magnetic field of the whole toroid, so I tried deriving it myself. I want to know whether I'm correct or not, and if not, what conceptual or mathematical mistake I made.

To find the average magnetic field, we need to find the magnetic field at every point in the toroid and divide it by the number of points.

**Method 1:**
First, I tried the basic mean value of a function method: $$B_\text{average}=\frac{\int_{r_1}^{r_2}\frac{\mu_0 NI}{2\pi r}dr}{\int_{r_1}^{r_2}dr}=\frac{\mu_0NI}{2\pi(r_2-r_1)}\ln\left(\frac{r_2}{r_1}\right)$$
$$\therefore \frac{\mu_0 NI}{2\pi r_\text{average}}=\frac{\mu_0NI}{2\pi(r_2-r_1)}\ln\left(\frac{r_2}{r_1}\right)$$
$$\therefore r_\text{average}=\frac{r_2-r_1}{\ln\left(\frac{r_2}{r_1}\right)}$$

This doesn't match the given $r_\text{average}$, but I realized that this is on a horizontal plane and does not take into account the 3D shape of the toroid i.e. only the points on the horizontal plane containing the geometrical center of the toroid are taken into account since the integration is done linearly where $dr$ is some small cicular ring element on the horizontal plane.

[image: Linear integration]

So I tried a different method:

**Method 2:**
The toroid is a series of infinite infinitesimally thin chips arranged vertically into a circular pattern. Like this but many more:

[image: Chips]

If we can find the average magnetic field of one of the chip, we have found the average magnetic field of the whole toroid since if we average the magnetic field of all the (let's say $n$) chips, we will get the same value since each chip is identical. $$B_\text{average}=\frac{nB_\text{chip}}{n}=B_\text{chip}$$where

$B_\text{chip}=$ Average magnetic field of one chip

$n=$ number of chips

To calculate the average magnetic field of a chip, we need to find $\frac{\int{}{}B dA}{\int dA}$, where $A=$ area. Essentially a weighted average.

To find $\int BdA$, let's take a look at a vertical cross-section:

[image: Diagram 1]

We take an infinitesimally small strip element $dx$ on the horizontal axis at an distance x from the center of the toroid. The magnetic field (horizontally) in the element is assumed to be constant across such a small distance. Note that the magnetic field is same at distance $x$ irrespective of vertical position (height) since using ACL, if we take a an Ampèrian loop of radius $x$ and at a height $h$, the total current passing through will still be $NI$ and the magnetic field at that $h$ will be $B=\frac{\mu_0 NI}{2\pi x}$

$$\therefore \int BdA=\int\frac{\mu_0 NI}{2\pi x} \times h \times dx$$

Looking at the diagram above, we can see that $$h=R\sin{\theta}$$ and $$x=r_1+R-R\cos{\theta}=r_1+R(1-\cos{\theta})$$

Let's take an infinitesimally small angle $d\theta=\angle AOB$.

Length of arc subtended by $d\theta=Rd\theta=AB$.

Taking a closer look at the arc $AB$:
[image: Arc closeup]

$OB$ is perpendicular to $AB$ since it is a radius of a circle and the rest of the angles follow. $$\therefore dx=Rd\theta\times\sin{\theta}=R\sin{\theta}d\theta$$
$$\therefore \int BdA=\int\frac{\mu_0 NI}{2\pi x} \times R\sin{\theta} \times R\sin{\theta}d\theta$$
$$\Longrightarrow\frac{\mu_0 NIR^2}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2{\theta}}{r_1+R(1-\cos{\theta})}d\theta$$
Using $R=\frac{r_2-r_1}{2}$,
$$\Longrightarrow\frac{\mu_0 NIR^2}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2{\theta}}{\frac{r_1+r_2}{2}+\left(\frac{r_1-r_2}{2}\right)\cos{\theta}}d\theta$$
$$\Longrightarrow\frac{\mu_0 NIR^2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2{\theta}}{\left(r_1+r_2\right)+\left(r_1-r_2\right)\cos{\theta}}d\theta$$
Let $a=(r_1+r_2)$ and $b=(r_1-r_2)$
Therefore we need to find $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2{\theta}}{a+b\cos{\theta}}d\theta$, which is equal to $\frac{2\pi}{b^2}\left(a - \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}\right)$ ([Source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1777145/evaluate-int-02-pi-frac-sin2xa-b-cosx-dx-using-a-suitable-cont))
$$\Longrightarrow\frac{\mu_0 NIR^2}{\pi}\frac{2\pi}{b^2}\left(a - \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}\right)$$
$$\Longrightarrow\frac{2\mu_0 NIR^2}{(r_1-r_2)^2}\left(r_1+r_2 - \sqrt{(r_1+r_2)^2 - (r_1-r_2)^2}\right)$$
$$\Longrightarrow\frac{2\mu_0 NIR^2}{(r_1-r_2)^2}\left(r_1+r_2 - 2\sqrt{r_1r_2}\right)$$
$$\therefore B_\text{average}=B_\text{chip}=\frac{\frac{2\mu_0 NIR^2}{(r_1-r_2)^2}\left(r_1+r_2 - 2\sqrt{r_1r_2}\right)}{\pi R^2}$$
$$\Longrightarrow\frac{2\mu_0 NI\left(r_1+r_2 - 2\sqrt{r_1r_2}\right)}{\pi (r_1-r_2)^2}$$
$$\therefore \frac{\mu_0 NI}{2\pi r_\text{average}}=\frac{2\mu_0 NI\left(r_1+r_2 - 2\sqrt{r_1r_2}\right)}{\pi (r_1-r_2)^2}$$
$$\therefore r_\text{average}=\frac{(r_1-r_2)^2}{4\left(r_1+r_2 - 2\sqrt{r_1r_2}\right)}$$

This also doesn't match $\frac{r_1+r_2}{2}$ but I realized my mistake that this also doesn't take into account the whole torus. For example, if we take two points equidistant (distance < R) from the center of cross-section of the toroid, the contribution of the both the strips is the same in terms of area but inside the whole torus, the actual contribution of the strip farther away from the center of the toroid is more since the radius is larger and therefore circumference is larger. Therefore we need to integrate on the whole toroid in 3 dimensions i.e. in terms of volume.

**Method 3:**
The toroid can be considered as a series of infinite infinitesimally thin rings arranged concentrically. Like this but many more:
[image: Torus as rings]
$$B_\text{average}=\frac{\int BdV}{\int dV}=\frac{\int BdV}{V}$$
where $$V=2\pi\times\text{average radius}\times\pi R^2 = 2\pi^2\frac{(r_1+r_2)}{2}R^2=\pi^2(r_1+r_2)R^2$$
using the same notation as above,
$$dV=2\times h\times dx\times 2\pi x$$
$$\therefore \int BdV=\int \frac{\mu_0 NI}{2\pi x}\times4h\pi xdx$$
$$\Longrightarrow 2\mu_0 NI\int_{0}^{\pi}R\sin{\theta}R\sin{\theta}d\theta$$
$$\Longrightarrow 2\mu_0 NIR^2\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^2{\theta}d\theta$$
$$\Longrightarrow \mu_0 NIR^2\pi$$
$$\therefore B_\text{average} = \frac{\mu_0 NIR^2\pi}{\pi^2(r_1+r_2)R^2}$$
$$\Longrightarrow \frac{\mu_0 NI}{\pi(r_1+r_2)}$$
$$\Longrightarrow \frac{\mu_0 NI}{2\pi r_\text{average}}=\frac{\mu_0 NI}{\pi(r_1+r_2)}$$
$$\therefore r_\text{average}=\frac{r_1+r_2}{2}$$

Now this does match the answer that is usually given but I want to know whether this is the actual derivation/answer or do we just approximate $r_\text{average}$ as $\frac{r_1+r_2}{2}$ since both the previous methods(1 and 2) give an answer quite close to $\frac{r_1+r_2}{2}$.